# Is this theorem wrong?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

From Schaum's Outline of Theory and Problems of Discrete Mathematics

> Theorem 2.3: Let $R$ be a relation on a set $A$. Then:
>   $(i)$ $R\cup \Delta A$ is the reﬂexive closure of $R$.
>   $(ii)$ $R \cup R^{−1}$ is the symmetric closure of $R$.

I think the theorem is wrong.

For $(i)$, consider set $A = \{1, 2, 3,\}$
$R = \{(1,2) (2,1)\}$
The Reflexive closure of $R$ is $R \cup \{(1,1), (2,2)\}$ and not $R \cup \{(1,1) (2,2) (3,3)\}$
I do agree though, that the Reflexive closure of $R$ reflexive$(R) \subseteq R \cup \Delta A$

For $(ii)$ same argument $R \cup R^{-1}$ is $\Bbb U$ for the example above, $R$ is it's own Symmetric closure. And of course $R \in \Bbb U$.

Am I right? Are the two theorems indeed wrong, or am I missing something.

Comment: Personally, I have always known $\Delta$ to mean "symmetric difference," which is a binary operator (i.e., $A \Delta B$ where $A$ and $B$ are both sets). Therefore, $\Delta A$ does not really make sense. What do you mean by $\Delta A$?

Comment: He means the diagonal of the cartesian product, i.e. $\{(a,a) \mid a \in A\}$.

Comment: @SteamyRoot Thanks!

Comment: @NobleMushtak: It’s more often written $\Delta_A$, and as **SteamyRoot** says, it’s the diagonal in $A\times A$.

Comment: @basket: That’s implicit in the statement that $R$ is a relation on the set $A$.

Comment: The reflexive closure of your $R$ **as a relation on** $A$ is $R\cup\{\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 2,2\rangle,\langle 3,3\rangle\}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(i) $R \cup \{(1,1),(2,2)\}$ is not the reflexive closure of $R$. A reflexive relation $S$ on $A$ is a relation such that for all $x \in A$, we have $(x,x) \in S$. However, $(3, 3) \notin R \cup \{(1,1),(2,2)\}$, so $R \cup \{(1,1),(2,2)\}$ is not reflexive.

(ii) You are right in that in your example, $R$ is its own symmetric closure. However, your example also has that $R=R \cup R^{-1}$, so $R \cup R^{-1}$ is the symmetric closure of $R$, even in your example.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've seen my misunderstandings.